# MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx deadlocks the main STA thread in MFC application

Tags: multithreading, com, synchronization, deadlock, sta

What is the best was to do STA thread synchronization?

I have a dialog based MFC application with two STA threads: the main and the second. I created the COM object in the main UI thread.

I call the COM interface from the second thread. In the main thread, to make sure the second thread finishes before the main thread proceeds, I use a loop to wait for the thread. This loop calls MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(timout=500) looply.

I immediately got deadlocked on the wait. Then I realized that the MFC message pump, AfxInternalPumpMessage(), only helps with blocking calls but doesn't help at all with deadlock situations.

Then I added Peek/Translate/DispatchMessage code into the wait loop and then all worked.

Now, it seems that without hand coding the Peek/Translate/DispatchMessage loop, you can't do STA threads synchronization at all? Any wait call will deadlock you. Then what's the best or standard way to synchronize STA threads?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to call MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx? In the second thread, why not post a message to the first thread when it's done?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for [`CoWaitForMultipleHandles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

> If the caller resides in a single-thread
>   apartment, CoWaitForMultipleHandles enters the COM modal loop, and the thread's
>   message loop will continue to dispatch
>   messages using the thread's message
>   filter. If no message filter is registered
>   for the thread, the default COM
>   message processing is used.

Answer (score 0):

Not any wait, but any wait that stops running the message loop will indeed deadlock you. The solution is to interleave your wait loop and message loop processing - wait a little, then process all pending messages, repeat.

Comment: Isn't MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx the wait that can be configured to return when a message is added to the queue. Also isn't GetMessage a wait function?

Comment: @David Heffernan: No, if you carefully read the MSDN description of that function you'll see that it it not interrupted with a message.

Comment: I guess I'm reading it wrong then but what do the QS_ wake masks do?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Yes, you're right - the function will return on a message, but you have to dispatch the message yourself anyway: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/01/26/517849.aspx

Comment: @sharptooth's link is currently at ["Pumping messages while waiting for a period of time"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060126-00/?p=32513).